# Directly encrypt ncdu export with aespipe

Tags: encryption, aes, password-protection

I successfully use the ncdu export function:

`ncdu -1xo- -e /media/xxx | gzip > xxx.ncdu.gz`

And extract/use it after when I want :

`zcat xxx.ncdu.gz | ncdu -f- --color dark -e`

Now I would like do the same, but to get a encrypted file (with password asked) as output. The aim is that the export is directly exported encrypted, so no readable export on the device without the password.
I tried :

`ncdu -1xo- -e /media/xxx | gzip | aespipe > xxx.ncdu.gz.aes`

But I think the ncdu start listing while aespipe is asking password, so it doesn't work.
Is there a way to do this in one bash line, first the password is asked, then the ncdu start and store the result in the encrypted gzip output?

Maybe I could use:

```
echo "entrez le mot de passe" && read mypassword && ncdu -1xo- -e /media/xxx | gzip | aespipe -P $mypassword > xxx.ncdu.gz.aes | mypassword=""
```

But I don't know if it is safe or if the password is stored somewhere? In fact the password is displayed and it better shouldn't.

Anyway, after that I am unable to use the encrypted (is it really done?) export with ncdu:

```
echo "entrez le mot de passe" && read mypassword && zcat aespipe -d -P $mypassword xxx.ncdu.gz.aes | ncdu -f- --color dark -e | mypassword=""
```

What am I missing? I think aespipe is waiting a password file instead a user entry.

I tried this with openssl too:

```
echo "entrez le mot de passe" && read mypassword && ncdu -1xo- -e /media/xxx | gzip | openssl enc -base64 -e -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:$mypassword > xxx.ncdu.gz.openssl | mypassword=""
```

with no more success

Thanks for reading, sorry for my terrible English level :)